# How to read and update row in file with Java

Tags: java

currently i creating a java apps and no database required
that why i using text file to make it
the structure of file is like this

```
unique6id username identitynumber point

unique6id username identitynumber point
```

may i know how could i read and find match unique6id then update the correspond row of point ?

Sorry for lack of information
and here is the part i type is

```
public class Cust{
  string name;
  long idenid, uniqueid;
  int pts;
  customer(){}
  customer(string n,long ide, long uni, int pt){
        name = n;
        idenid = ide;
        uniqueid = uni;
        pts = pt;
  }


FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("Data.txt", true);
            BufferedWriter fbw = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
                Cust newCust = new Cust();

                newCust.name = memUNTF.getText();
                newCust.ic = Long.parseLong(memICTF.getText());
                newCust.uniqueID = Long.parseLong(memIDTF.getText());
                newCust.pts= points;

            fbw.write(newCust.name + " " + newCust.ic + " " + newCust.uniqueID + " " + newCust.point);
            fbw.newLine();
            fbw.close();
```

this is the way i text in the data
then the result inside Data.txt is

```
spencerlim 900419129876 448505 0
Eugene 900419081234 586026 0
```

when user type in 586026 then it will grab row of eugene
bind into Cust
and update the pts (0 in this case, try to update it into other number eg. 30)

Thx for reply =D

Comment: Post what you have so far, and what your results are. It will help people help you a lot better!

Comment: sorry for lack of detail and hope to get the right answer for this case =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading is pretty easy, but updating a text file in-place (ie without rewriting the whole file) is very awkward.

So, you have two options:

1. Read the whole file, make your changes, and then write the whole file to disk, overwriting the old version; this is quite easy, and will be fast enough for small files, but is not a good idea for very large files.
2. Use a format that is not a simple text file. A database would be one option (and bear in mind that there is one, Derby, built into the JDK); there are other ways of keeping simple key-value stores on disk (like a HashMap, but in a file), but there's nothing built into the JDK.

Comment: seriously, damn hard to play around with text file... anyway~ i requesting permission from lecturer for using database in this assignment, Thx =D

Comment: @Spencer Lim: Good. Tell him we told you use a database, and if he doesn't let you, we're going to come round and do him over.

Comment: Asked her, and the truth is she don't know how to that's why she tell us to use file stream XD and now, my application success to function with database =D

Answer (score 2):

You can use [OpenCSV with custom separators](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#custom-sepators).

Here's a sample method that updates the info for a specified user:

```
public static void updateUserInfo(
    String userId,  // user id
    String[] values // new values
) throws IOException{
    String fileName = "yourfile.txt.csv";
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName), ' ');
    List<String[]> lines = reader.readAll();
    Iterator<String[]> iterator = lines.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        String[] items = (String[]) iterator.next();
        if(items[0].equals(userId)){
            for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
                String value = values[i];
                if(value!=null){ 
                    // for every array value that's not null,
                    // update the corresponding field
                    items[i+1]=value;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(fileName), ' ').writeAll(lines);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use InputStream(s) and Reader(s) to read file. 
Here is a code snippet that shows how to read file.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("c:/myfile.txt")));

String line = null;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // do something with the line.
}
```

Use OutputStream and Writer(s) to write to file. Although you can use random access files, i.e. write to the specific place of the file I do not recommend you to do this. Much easier and robust way is to create new file every time you have to write something. I know that it is probably not the most efficient way, but you do not want to use DB for some reasons... If you have to save and update partial information relatively often and perform search into the file I'd recommend you to use DB. There are very light weight implementations including pure java implementations (e.g. h2: http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html).